# Begin try drop vs if exists differences

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

Can someone ELI5 (Explain Like I'm 5) the difference between using begin try drop and if exists when utilizing temp tables in SQL Server?

I have found that begin try drop seems to work better when used in outside programming languages, but have been told by a DBA that if exists is more efficient.

Just trying to understand the differences.

Thanks

Comment: There is a third option these days as well. `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`. Out of the two options you mention I agree with the DBA though not really for performance reasons. Just seems cleaner to do the check first rather than using exceptions for control flow. (exception handling does certainly have a performance penalty though) - and if you are just catching the error and ignoring it you might be missing other error causes

Comment: What is `ELI5`?

Comment: @Dalek  ELI5 is "Explain Like I’m 5”. It means using the simplest terms to describe a topic/concept.

Comment: OK, might be better to use regular English in that case.

Comment: @DaleK Feeling pretty good that I knew that one  :)

Comment: Good luck explaining database theory to a 5 year old lol

Comment: Any DBA who's concerned about the "efficiency" of the operation used to drop tables has too much time on their hands. The best way to optimize creating and dropping tables is to avoid doing so. Alternatives include things like memory-optimized tempdb, semi-permanent tables that are truncated rather than dropped and recreated, but first and most of all of course proving that this is worth worrying about in the first place. Note that (non-global) temp tables, in particular, are automatically dropped when their scope ends, making explicitly dropping them (by whatever means) a silly exercise.